# How to disable/exclude unneeded operations while using tesseract?

Tags: c++, tesseract

Suppose I need to recognize single word or even a letter. So I need not find rows of text, deskew them, split into words...

How to run recognition process with these exclusions?

I see only was to set rectangle, but this also does not mean that all steps won't be performed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting rectangle and page segmentation mode should do.